# How can I set a column vertically middled?

Tags: tables, wrap, tabulary

I have a table in my document, because of long text, I used tabulary. Now I have a problem with it. Because it didn't support setting middle. What should I do now?
Change my tabulary package?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabulary}

\begin {document}

    \begin {table}[h]
    \centering
    \label{t4}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
    \begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{RCCCC}
    A long title that is wrapped on several lines & A long title that is wrapped on several lines & A long title that is wrapped on several lines \\
    \hline 
    A random text & 1 & 0.025 \\
    \hline
    A quite long random text (wrapped on 3 lines)  & 2 & 2 \\
    \hline
    A quite long random text (wrapped on 3 lines)  & 2 & 2 \\
    \hline

    \end{tabulary}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the `tabu` package.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabu}
\begin{document}
\begin {table}[h]
\centering
\tabulinesep = 3pt
\begin{tabu}to \linewidth{X[1, r, m]*2{X[1, c, m]}}
A long title that is wrapped on several lines & A long title that is wrapped on several lines & A long title that is wrapped on several lines \\
\hline
A random text & 1 & 0.025 \\
\hline
A quite long random text (wrapped on 3 lines)  & 2 & 2 \\
\hline
A quite long random text (wrapped on 3 lines)  & 2 & 2 \\
\hline
\end{tabu}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

> [image]
> <sub>(source: [sinaimg.cn](https://ww1.sinaimg.cn/large/005yyi5Jjw1envhj67yprj318e0hagqt.jpg))</sub>

Comment: It seems that tabu is a very strong package, did u have a good reference for lraning about it?

Comment: @SeyedAmirMousavian See [the manual of the `tabu` package](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tabu/tabu.pdf). Typing `texdoc tabu` in your terminal will also give you the manual.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution by declaring two new colummn types: `\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}` and `\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}m{#1}}`.
You can manually adjust the width by C{width} and R{width}.

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\begin{document}

    \begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \label{t4}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
    \begin{tabular}{R{3cm}C{3cm}C{3cm}}
    A long title that is wrapped on several lines & A long title that is wrapped on several lines & A long title that is wrapped on several lines \\
    \hline 
    A random text & 1 & 0.025 \\
    \hline
    A quite long random text (wrapped on 3 lines)  & 2 & 2 \\
    \hline
    A quite long random text (wrapped on 3 lines)  & 2 & 2 \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```